# Layout setup with fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I've just started converting my apps to use fragments.  I have a ListView activity and a "Details" activity, which the user goes to after selecting an item in the Listview.  I've converted them to fragments successfully, however, I have a header in the layout of each activity.  The ListView has a "reload" icon in the header, but the header in the details does not.

Everything works fine when I'm viewing the app in portrait, but I have a layout in the "layout-land" folder which contains both fragments, so, when viewing in landscape, you see both the ListView and the "Details" view. The problem is the header layout is shown in both fragments.

My question is what is the best practice for covering my layouts to the new fragment setup?  I'm thinking, instead of having the header in each fragment's layout, I just add it to the layout that contains both fragments?

Sorry if this is just obvious question, I'm still trying to wrap my head around the whole fragments paradigm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's why the use of ActionBar is recommended. If you include an action bar in your app with a refresh button , users will know (and learn) to use that button. The onClick implementation is all yours and you could refresh the list adapters accordingly. There is no need to then build these UI elements in all your controls.

Comment: So is the general consensus to use ActionBarSherlock, since I'm targeting pre-3.0 devices?

Comment: Its quite popular and flexible.